# Windows 2000 Server failed drive recovery

Tags: data-recovery, windows-server-2000

Does anyone have any suggestions or recommendations for good data recovery software for a Windows 2000 Server. The most important drive recently failed and while there was a backup, it was two weeks ago. The data from last week is most important and needs to be recovered off of drive. I would appreciate any suggestions or recommendations or reviving the drive as well.

Thanks

Comment: If you're going to use a data recovery firm to physically recover data from the drive (disassemble in a cleanroom, etc) then the less you play around with the drive the better. Each time you try to spin the drive you may be doing further damage.

Comment: The most important drive should be the most frequently backed up.

Answer (score 1):

I have used ERD commander before Windows bought the company who built that tool. Now it seems the name has changed to MS Dart.

ERD is still one of the tools on MS Dart so you could follow the instructions at the below link to create a bootable CD to boot into your Server and launch the Disk Recovery tool.

Please note that it seems you may need Windows 7 or later to be able to have the option within windows to create this Bootable CD however. Also if its an actual bad drive, you may make it worse by booting into it as posted in first post.

Here is the MS Link:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee532075.aspx